# How can I use the Ajax response in another function

Tags: php

I have a dropdown list with values from the database. I used AJAX to dynamically display the price of the selected item form the database. I want to use the price value for further processing

Comment: Can you give us a HTML code, of generated page, so we could help you?

Answer (score 2):

```
 var dataForFuture;

 $.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
      dataForFuture = data;
      // other code...
 });
```